# GIT Changed Files Between two Branches

Tags: git, git-log, git-history-graph

I have a specific question to GIT History.
It is possible to compare two branches and get a list with all files there changed? If yes then tell me how, please.

The reason is I need merge a branch in the other branch. From a developer there is not aviable anymore... And I need to know which files he has changed.

Thanks a lot,
Florian

Comment: `git diff`?////

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the diff between two branches -

```
git diff branch1 branch2
```

Use `stat` param to list only differing files.

```
git diff --stat branch1 branch2
```

Comment: It is possible  only show the name of the files without quellcode report and possible to save the logs ? 

Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please mark it as correct answer if it solved your problem.